# CSOM CAML Query - is there a returned fields limit?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, caml-query

I've just noticed that that there is a difference in result when searching for a list item with CAML Query and getting it by ID.

Following piece of code returns item with 100 FieldValues:

```
var item = sourceList.GetItemById(1);
ctx.Load(item);
await ctx.ExecuteQueryRetryAsync();
```

While the following piece returns only 97 FieldValues:

```
var queryTxt = $"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" /><Value Type=\"Integer\">1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
var query = new CamlQuery()
        {
            ViewXml = queryTxt
        };
var itemList = sourceList.GetItems(query);
ctx.Load(itemList);
await ctx.ExecuteQueryRetryAsync();
var item = itemsList.FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there anything I've missed?

Edit:
If I invoke it like this, I also get 100 FieldValues

```
var queryTxt = $"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" /><Value Type=\"Integer\">1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
var query = new CamlQuery()
    {
        ViewXml = queryTxt
    };
var itemList = sourceList.GetItems(query);
ctx.Load(itemList);
await ctx.ExecuteQueryRetryAsync();
var item = itemsList.FirstOrDefault();
ctx.Load(item);
await ctx.ExecuteQueryRetryAsync();
```

Comment: Do you have exactly 100 fields in your list, or are both of these getting you less than all columns?  Can you do a compare between the result sets and see which three columns are missing from the camlQuery results?  The types of the columns or the data present may give us a clue as to what is happening.

Comment: Not sure how many fields are there exactly and not really able to check it right now but (no access) but the missing field was a Person field.

Comment: If there are specific fields you need from that set of 100-or-so, you may be better off specifying `ViewFields` in your CAML to get exactly the fields you need.  With that many columns available, if you only need a handful of them, you're pulling down a much larger payload than you need.  Plus, if you can figure out exactly which three were missing, you could specify those three in `ViewFields` to see if they still fail to be retrieved when explicitly requested.

Comment: The problem is that this is happening inside our "CopyListItem" function which is used to copy all the values of all "custom" fields. As the method is being used globally to duplicate items between sites and lists I am not able to predefine the fields.

Comment: A few years ago, I had a similar issue on a server-side api CAML query was excluding all taxonomy fields for some unknown reason.  Technically, we didn't solve the issue, do much as worked around it.  We changed our query to only return the ID field to keep the query result as small and quick as possible, then did a GetItemById on the returned value.  Creates a double lookup, but when the problem is inside the api, sometimes you have to code around the bug.

Answer (score 0):

It should return the same FieldValues count for the item returned from CAML or getting by Id, here is the test capture in my side:

Get List Item (Id:1) with CAML, return 63 FieldValues when tracing:

[image]

Get List Item By Id directly, the FieldValues is the same 63:

[image]

Comment: Yes, from my experience it should return the same number of fields. However when checking this in debug it is not the case and there is a difference.

Comment: Can you create a new list and then check to see if you can get the same fieldValues count ?